# How to Open pdf file link from the web-page launched in ionic2 app using inAppBrowser

Tags: ionic2, inappbrowser

I am facing issue to open pdf file link from the web-page which was launched in ionic2 app using InAppBrowser. Using following code:

```
this.iab.create(url, "_self", {location : 'no',hidden : 'no'});
```

I can open the pdf file link if we launched the web-page using:

```
this.iab.create(url, "_system", {location : 'no',hidden : 'no'});
```

Comment: Which platform are you testing on? iOS/Android? Why not use _system if it works?

Comment: i am testing over android. we cant use _system because using _system web page will be open in browser out side the app and also before opening the web-page it will ask for select the app to open any web-page.

Comment: i can open the pdf link's using _system when pdf link are added in app code its self. but my issue is we have pdf link in web-page which was launched using _system.